# Function inequality : $h(x)=2x$

Tags: functions, inequality, functional-equations

I have a function for which:
$h(x) \leq 2x$ and $h(x+y)\leq h(x)+h(y)$. I must prove that $h(x)=2x$. I tried show that $h(x)\geq 2x$, but with no effects. Do you have any hint?

Comment: Should the second inequality be $h(x+y)\le h(x)+h(y)$? Because currently, for $x=y=-1$, I get that the second inequality gives $2(-2)=-4\le 2(-2-2)=-8$ for $h(x)=2x$

Comment: @Joe Not just for specific values, but e.g. if $h(x) = x \le 2x$ one gets $h(x + y) = x + y \le 2(x + y) = 2(h(x) + h(y))$ so clearly there is a problem with the conditions.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó: $x \le 2x$ does not hold for negative $x$, so (assuming that the domain is $\Bbb R$) that is not a counterexample.

Comment: @MartinR Right, I left out $x > 0$.

Comment: I did consider that perhaps the domain was intended to be nonnegative, but then $h(x)=0$ would satisfy the conditions.

Comment: Perhaps there should be no $2$ in the RHS of second condition.

Comment: Yes, without 2.

Comment: Isn't there also a typo between any of the $h(x)$ vs $2x$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=0$ in the first inequality and $y=0$ in the second inequality. This gives $h(0)\le 0$ and $h(x)\le h(x) + h(0)$. Therefore, $h(0)=0$.

Now, put $y=-x$ in the second inequality and use the first inequality for $x$ and $-x$ to obtain
$$0 = h(0) \le h(x)+h(-x) \le 2x -2x =0.$$

Therefore, all the used inequalities are equalities and $h(x) = 2x$, as desired.